# Puppet hiera and create_resource issue

Tags: ruby, puppet, hiera

I'm having some issues with passing a hash from hiera through to a resource creation.

```
vhosts:
    project_1:
        name: project_1
        project_name: project_1
    project_2:
        name: project_2
        project_name: project_2

$vhosts = hiera('vhosts', [])
create_resources(project_vhosts::vhosts, $vhosts)
```

Ignore the hidden project names :) but you get the gist. My resource looks like this:

```
define project_vhosts::vhosts(
$vhosts = []
){
    notice($vhosts)
}
```

I get these errors after my puppet run

```
Error: Invalid parameter project_name on project_vhosts::Vhosts[project_1] on node *
Wrapped exception:
Invalid parameter project_name
Error: Invalid parameter project_name on project_vhosts::Vhosts[project_1] on *
```

I get that it wants me to implement the parameters directly into the class. However what I really want is the hash available as a whole to me in the resource. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason you don't want `create_resources` to map your configuration data to parameters? That's its sole purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First off, please don't use `[]` to denote an empty hash. It's not. `[]` is the empty array, and `{}` is the empty hash.

To do what you want, your data just need one more layer of hashing.

```
vhost_data:
    vhosts:
        project_1:            
            name: project_1
            project_name: project_1
        project_2:
            name: project_2
            project_name: project_2
```

Then

```
$data = hiera('vhost_data', {})
create_resources(project_vhosts::vhosts, $vhosts)
```

Of course, there is yet a simpler way to do all of that with your data.

```
project_vhosts::vhosts {
   'meaningless-resource-title':
       vhosts => hiera('vhosts', {})
}
```